# maintain logged-in status across sub-domains?

Tags: cookies, subdomain, authentication

Is there a way to maintain logged-in status across sub-domains? I've tried adding a cookie prefix in config.php to no avail... not sure what else to try.

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you can set a "cookie_domain" variable to the config.php. Just figured this out by having a quick look at expressionengine/core/EE_Config.php around line 277. For cross sub domains persisting cookie, I believe your domain should be one of the seven special ones (http://wp.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html). In short $config['cookie_domain'] = ".yourdomain.com" would be worth a try!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable multi-site login via the `config.php` file. You add a statement like:

```
$config['multi_login_sites'] = "http://domain.org/|http://domain2.org/";
```

for each site/domain that they are logging into. Now the downside of this, is if you are logging them into a number of sites, the user will see a series of login flashes, from the EE successful login screen. I'm not certain if there is a way to remove that.

I know for the clients we've done this for, we reduced the multi-site logins to just the sites were people could place orders, submit forms, etc., as opposed to trying to login them into all sub sites at once.

If there are a lot of sites, and the user needs to be logged into all of them, then I recommend taking a look at [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701922/how-does-facebook-set-cross-domain-cookies-for-iframes-on-canvas-pages) question and response, on how sites like Facebook handle it.

Comment: This is really great info, never knew about this approach - However in this particular case it's all about sub-domains of a single TLD, not multiple domain names, and as such the answer from @mfauveau works. Also reveals to me what the member_member_login_multi extension hook might be for... never understood that before due to apparent lack of docs... http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_auth/index.html#member-member-login-multi